# Tapku Load time is extremely long

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, tapku

I've created a "home" viewcontroller which pushes a "calendar" viewcontroller.
The calendar viewcontroller uses the TAPKU library to create a calendar which I load with events from a plist.

The problem I'm having is that the load time for the calendar viewcontroller is Extremely long!

It consistently takes around 4 to 5 seconds to load that calendar.
Additionally, when I reload the calendar in the calendar viewcontroller, it takes 2 to 3 seconds.

Any advice on how to make it load faster?
Thanks!

Comment: how much events are you using? show delegates methods for tapku kalendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tapku load times are a bit longer for iPod Generation 2 and below and iPhone generation 3 and below. Anything else though, is a lot faster!